# Front Derailleur 10T Capacity (XT FD-M8025)

Tags: mountain-bike, shimano

I'd like to move from a 1x11 crankset to a 2x11 crankset to extend both my high and low gear range.

Shimano has indicated that their XT M8025 Front Derailler has a 10T capacity.  It means that I could only use a 10T set-up between my front chainrings, such as running a 36-26 combination (10T difference).

My goal is to run a 36-24 combination (12T difference) with an XT 11-42 Cassette. Is it possible to run such a combination with an XT M8025 FD "without noticeable" impediments ?

Your answer or experience is appreciated. Bike tinkerers please chime in.  Thanks :)

Comment: More details would help - what cassette are you planning to run, what range are you aiming for?  I find it hard to imagine needing lower than a 26/42 low gear.

Comment: Shimano limits are notoriously conservative, so pushing one or two over is often workable, but I have never used this mech, so comment, not answer.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know the severity because I rarely encounter recent mountain FDs and hacky setups for them even less, but what will happen is the contact it makes with the chain when shifting off of the small ring will be suboptimal. That kind of problem will vary with what cog the chain is on in back, i.e. better in the lower gears. There can also be problems with the chain wanting to drag on the cage in some small/small combinations.

You'll probably get a better performing setup by running a wider cassette and cheating the RD total capacity. Shifting will be largely unaffected and you'll only be down the ability to use some small/small combos, which will be compromised anyway if you do what you propose.